# Won't dual boot---goes straight to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I have a Windows 7 computer. This is what I did:

1. Using Windows Disk Management, shrunk the available hard drive producing a partition more than large enough for Ubuntu.
2. Changed the boot order in BIOS to CD, USB, HDD.
3. Inserted Ubuntu 12.04 disk, launched Ubuntu.
4. Chose "Install alongside windows 7".
5. Successfully installed Ubuntu, restarted, and it goes straight to Ubuntu. No text screen to choose Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Just straight Ubuntu.
6. I can see the 2 normal windows partitions, in Ubuntu, access the data I want from it, but cannot get it to allow me to use windows as well.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm somewhat experienced with Windows/DOS, and utterly clueless regarding Ubuntu/Linux. Please understand I am semi-tech literate.

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Type your password and let the command run. This should update the bootloader so it can see Windows. When you restart the computer, there should be a screen for a few seconds that lets you choose between Windows and Ubuntu. If there isn't, then something is probably wrong with your Windows installation.

Comment: you sir, just saved my life. I cant thank you enough

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out Boot Repair.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I had a problem where I selected a wrong partition to write the boot loader and it wouldn't boot my Windows partition even thought I selected the option.

I used Boot Repair to fix everything.

Note in the link the 2nd option talks about using a Live installation. I just installed and ran Boot Repair from my already installed Ubuntu 12.04 installation and it solved my problems just fine.