# Windows won't boot after unsuccessful Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, data-recovery

Windows 7
HP Laptop
3 gig ram
2.1 or 2.6ghz
Not sure about the rest

Well, I tried to install Ubuntu and be able to dual boot alongside windows. Simple procedure and I followed it to the T. Needless to say, it wont recognize my default hard drive or any of the partitions. Booting via my flash drive will let me use the Ubuntu OS, will enable access to my file system, and will let me back up the files. Done. So now I need to reinstall Windows but any option I use to try to reinstall the factory image will not yeild a partion to choose. If I cant choose a partition to restore, how can I restore Windows? Because if I have access to my files then nothing should be wrong with Windows, but it still wont boot. I have the flash drive set to priority on the boot order right now but I have tried every option. I've tried with the Windows CD and no partitions are availabe. Yet booting in Ubuntu I can see all the partitions like nothing is wrone. Anyone have an idea of what I did and how I can recover so I dont need to reinstall?

To add insult to injury, I unsuccessfully installed Ubuntu. It would not install to the partition I made prior to my attempt. My problem is I know how to do all the steps I have done today and nothing is making sense. Upvote for every answer! I need help! lol Thanks in advance, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice -

You might want to try and use Boot Repair. Check this topic -
[Won't dual boot---goes straight to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262521/wont-dual-boot-goes-straight-to-ubuntu/262526#262526)

The UEFI could also be causing you some problems -
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. I hope I was clear, I never installed Ubuntu on my computer because it wouldnt install on the partition I made. So I'm using Ubuntu via the flash drive. @jimbochou

Answer (score 0):

- Change the `UEFI` mode to `legacy mode` in bios.
- Boot into `ubuntu livecd`,connect to the internet and then follow the below steps

**Move/Resize or Delete a partition**

- Open the terminal and type the below commands to install `gparted`

  `sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted`

From that you can move,resize,delete a partition.

**Reinstalling the grub**

- Type the following commands in terminal to install **boot-repair**.

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
- Click `Recommended Repair`.

It will reinstall the grub which solves the booting problems.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this now. I hope I was clear, I never installed Ubuntu on my computer because it wouldnt inst all on the partition I made. So I'm using Ubuntu via the flash drive. @Avinash Raj